# problem with interpolation function of i18next with jquery

Tags: jquery, i18next

I have a problem with the interpolation function of (i18next with jquery) this is my code when i try to do that :

```
i18next.t("intro.title", {
    userEmail: "email@email.com"
})
```

nothing happen and in the web page i see my h1 element with "Landing Page for {{userEmail}}" without my variable value instead of {{userEmail}} and in the console i dont have error. Someone can help me"

this is the code of my page :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/i18next@21.6.10/i18next.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-i18next@1.2.1/jquery-i18next.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/i18next-browser-languagedetector@6.1.3/i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>
    <h1 data-i18n="intro.title"></h1>
    <h3 data-i18n="intro.subTitle"></h3>
    <select name="language" id="languageSwitcher"></select>

    <script>
        const lngs = {
            en: {
                nativeName: 'English'
            },
            it: {
                nativeName: 'Italian'
            }
        };

        const rerender = () => {

            $('body').localize();
        }

        $(function() {
            i18next
                .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
                .init({
                    debug: true,
                    fallbackLng: 'en',
                    resources: {
                        en: {
                            translation: {
                                intro: {
                                    title: 'Landing Page for {{userEmail}}',
                                    subTitle: 'Some subtitle'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        de: {
                            translation: {
                                intro: {
                                    title: 'sito per {{userEmail}}',
                                    subTitle: 'sottotitolo'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, (err, t) => {
                    if (err) return console.error(err);

                    jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $, {
                        useOptionsAttr: true
                    });

                    Object.keys(lngs).map((lng) => {
                        const opt = new Option(lngs[lng].nativeName, lng);
                        if (lng === i18next.resolvedLanguage) {
                            opt.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
                        }
                        $('#languageSwitcher').append(opt);
                    });
                    $('#languageSwitcher').change((a, b, c) => {
                        const chosenLng = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
                        i18next.changeLanguage(chosenLng, () => {
                            rerender();
                        });
                    });

                    rerender();


                })

        });
        i18next.t("intro.title", {
            userEmail: "email@email.com"
        })
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using jquery i18next function (.localize)